# issue with HiperX QuadCast and windows 8

Tags: windows-8, audio, microphone

I have bought a HyperX Quadcast microphone and I have some questions about its performance in Windows 8. I have configured the microphone in the cardiod mode and with a volume of 2, and I am using this mic for Blackboard. The settings on my OS are the following:

[image: y]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have placed the mic on the right side of the monitor, as it is marked by the X in the following figure:

[image]

The problem that I have is that when I record the sound on BB Collaborate Ultra, I can hear it that it is not so strong the sound. At the beginning I was thinking that it was a problem with my headset which is a simple one like this:

[image]

But when I listen to Youtube videos, for example, the sound is not so low. I would like to know what I am doing wrong with the configuration? I do not want to put the mic in front of me, because I need to use the keyboard. Also I found some reviews of this mic that they sound quite nice.

Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sound follows the [inverse square law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law), the same as light & many other things.
In short, you double the distance you quarter the input level.

Basically, without needing any calculations or math, the mic is *waaaay* further away than it needs to be to get similar pickup levels as your headset.

The only 'fix' is for it to be closer to you.
In a regular [noisy] consumer environment, at that distance you're going to be hearing as much background noise as voice.